# how to save an object form a observable

Tags: angular, spring-boot, http, observable

i created a http.get request in angular that returns an observable

```
findUserByEmail(email: string): Observable<User> {
return this.httpClient.get<User>(this.authBaseUri + '/users/' + email);
}
```

is there a way to save the user in a user object, so that i can do something with it later?
i wanna create more methods that returns the name, role, etc of that user but the user itself is always undefined...

I tried a lot but nothing worked :/

how would i for example write a getUserName() method to extract the username that should be in user.name?

thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

The this.httpClient.get() method returns an Observable, which means it represents a stream of data that is not immediately available. Since it is an asynchronous operation, you cannot access the user name directly after calling this.httpClient.get(). Instead, you need to subscribe to the Observable to get the user data once it's available.

Here's the corrected version of your code:

```
findUserByEmail(email: string): Observable<User> {
  const userObservable = this.httpClient.get<User>(this.authBaseUri + '/users/' + email);

  userObservable.subscribe(
    (user: User) => {
      console.log(user.name); // You can access the user name here
      // You can do something with the user data here, like saving it to a property
      // or triggering other methods that require the user data
    },
    (error: any) => {
      console.error('Error fetching user data:', error);
    }
  );

  return userObservable; // Return the Observable for further use, if needed
}
```

As you can see, we subscribe to the userObservable inside the findUserByEmail() method to get the user data. Once the data is available, the callback function provided to subscribe() is executed, and you can access the user name and perform other operations with the user data.

Keep in mind that using subscribe() makes the call asynchronous, so any code that requires the user data should be placed inside the subscription callback or triggered from there. If you need to return the user data or use it outside of the method, you can continue returning the userObservable as shown in the code. Other parts of your application can then subscribe to it to get the user data once it's available.

Comment: Please not subscribe in service. You can use [tap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap) rxjs/operator if you want store or log the response: `return this.httpClient.get(...).pipe(tap(user)=>{...})`

Answer (score 0):

If you use findUserByEmail method within angular component, you should create a component class property and call your method (most frequently inside ngOnInit) in maner as below:

```
@Component(...)
class YourComponent implements OnInit {      
  user: User;

  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    this.findUserByEmail(userEmail).subscribe(userData => this.user = userData);
  } 
  
  findUserByEmail(email: string): Observable<User> {
    ...
  }

}
```